# Regex to select between span content and then seperate result

Tags: php, regex

I am scraping parts of a webpage and then inserting the results into mySQL.

The source code of a problem area is:

```
<span class="profilelastlogin">
                    31,
                Kiev, Ukraine
                </span>
```

I want to select the 3 items, Age, City, Country and then assign them each to an individual varible.

I am using this regex to select to full string but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any guidance.

```
$regexAgeCityCountry = '/<span class="profilelastlogin">(.*?)<\/span>/';
                preg_match_all($regexAgeCityCountry, $page, $outputAgeCityCountry);
```

Comment: The way to scrap html content is to use an html parser (DOMDocument with DOMXPath for example), not a string extraction with regex or buildin string functions.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just match 3 separate groups?

```
 /<span class="profilelastlogin">(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)<\/span>/s
```

Group 1 contains the age, group 2 the city and group 3 contains the country.

You could also use this regex to make sure the age will always be numeric:

```
/<span class="profilelastlogin">([0-9]*),(.*?),(.*?)<\/span>/s
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe you have a type / not \ at beginning and end but yest that works great:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
                    34,
                Simferopol, Russian Federation
                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
                    34
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
                Simferopol
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Russian Federation
                
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the s (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier to treat your code as a single line, so the '.' will match newline characters.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is the php reference:

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class
>   such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the
>   setting of this modifier.

[Here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#PZbJYrsme) is a working example with a fix

Comment: Perfect, thanks. How do I assign each part between each , to a seperate variable?

Answer (score 0):

put all data in 1 variable first,  than

```
$arr = explode(',',$yourvariable);

$city = $arr[0];

$state = $arr[1]; 

$country = $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="profilelastlogin">\s+\K|\G(?!^)([^,]+),?\s*(?=[\s\S]*<\/span>)
```

You can try this to capture 3 parts.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/28

```
$re = "/<span class=\"profilelastlogin\">\\s+\\K|\\G(?!^)([^,]+),?\\s*(?=[\\s\\S]*<\\/span>)/mi";
$str = "<span class=\"profilelastlogin\">\n 31,\n Kiev, Ukraine\n </span>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```